# Is there a way to stop discord bit from running this code?

Tags: python, discord

Heyyyyy
I’m making a discord bot and it has a !kill command in it. You would use it like this:

!kill MySecretCode
!yes
Or
!no
Is there a way to prevent the code from listening to the !yes function after I do !no? Here’s the code (Python):

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Server Owner")
async def kill(ctx, code):
  if code == "MySecretCode":
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
    emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.orange(), title="**Terminate Bot?**",description=f"Are you sure you want to terminate this bot?\nTo continue with termination, type '!yes'.\nTo cancel the termination, type '!no'.")
    await channel.send(embed=emb)
    @client.command()
    async def yes(ctx):
      channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
      emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), title="**Terminating**",description=f"Process terminating...")
      await channel.send(embed=emb)
      await client.close()
      print("Bot terminated")
    @client.command()
    async def no(ctx):
      channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
      emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Termination Canceled**",description=f"You canceled the termination process")
      await channel.send(embed=emb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the `wait_for` function in discord.py that is made for this case. `wait_for` is an event function that will return the next-sent-message that matches the "check rule". It will only return or listen to 1 message. After returning the message object, the event will end.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Server Owner")
async def kill(ctx, code):
  def check_rule(message: discord.Message): # Checks if the author is the sender that triggered the !kill command.
    return message.author.id == ctx.message.author.id

  if code == "MySecretCode":
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
    emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.orange(), title="**Terminate Bot?**",description=f"Are you sure you want to terminate this bot?\nTo continue with termination, type '!yes'.\nTo cancel the termination, type '!no'.")
    await channel.send(embed=emb)


    try:
        # timeout after 10 seconds
        answer = (await client.wait_for('message', check=check_rule, timeout=10)).content
    except (asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError, 
        discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError):
        await ctx.send("Took too long to answer.")
        return

    if answer == '!yes':
       # turn off the bot
    elif answer == '!no':
       # don't turn off
    else:
       # invalid answer
```